# Multithreaded Pi Calculator Inconsistent Answers

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to create a simple program to calculate PI, and to teach myself how multi-threading works. Every time I run the program, I get a different answer for PI. I assume it has something to do with the Threads running in a different order every time, however I have called Thread.join() on every single Thread before I output my answer, so I am not sure why the order the calculations are done in would affect my final answer. I have also tried creating a synchronized method which I have named add in order to make the updating of the Pi variable thread safe, and adding the volatile modifier to my pi variable, however this has not stopped the problem from occurring. The code I have is held all in a single class, namely

```
public class Pi implements Runnable{
    static volatile double pi = 0;
    static long numRects = 100;
    static int rectsPerThread = 1   ;
    static double width = 1.0 / numRects;
    long start, end;

    public Pi(long start, long end){
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        double tmp = 0;
        for(long i = start; i < end; i++){
            tmp += Math.sqrt(1.0 - Math.pow(width * i, 2)) * width;
        }
        add(tmp);
    }

    private synchronized void add(double partOfPi){
        pi += partOfPi;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[(int)(numRects / rectsPerThread)];
        double start = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i  = 0; i < threads.length; i++){
            threads[i] = new Thread(new Pi(i * rectsPerThread, i * rectsPerThread + rectsPerThread));
            threads[i].start();
        }

        for(Thread t : threads){
            try{
                t.join();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        pi *= 4;
        System.out.println(pi);
        System.out.printf("Ran in: %.4fms", (System.nanoTime() - start) / Math.pow(10, 6));
    }
}
```

My questions are as follows: What am I doing wrong with my multi threading that would cause different answers to be returned every time, and how can I go about fixing this?

Comment: is the reading and writing of the value to `pi` threadsafe?

Comment: **Why** are you doing this? `Math.PI` exists.

Comment: @ScaryWombat that would probably explain what the issue is, however even after adding a synchronized method to add to Pi the same issue arises -- http://prntscr.com/f9ifq7

Comment: why not edit your question with this **new** code?

Comment: @ScaryWombat sounds like an excellent idea :) Do you have any feedback on why I am experiencing this error, however?

Comment: try making `pi` volatile

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have updated my original code to reflect this change, however this does not solve my issue. What is interesting is that my answer seems to remain the same, with a different answer once ever 5 or so times it is run.

Comment: Yes, I can see this. Using volatile or the answer below, the same behaviour seems to happen.  Maybe the value from `Math.sqrt(1.0 - Math.pow(width * i, 2)) * width` is not consistent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144606/discussion-between-quixotrykd-and-scary-wombat).

Comment: Sorry I do not have anything more to add, but to try to make single threaded and see if this phenomenon still happens

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the following,

```
var += expr;
```

is not an atomic operation. the old value is read, incremented, and written back, so it's not threadsafe. You need to guard against it with a semaphore.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
public class Pi implements Runnable{
    static double pi = 0;
    static long numRects = 100;
    static int rectsPerThread = 1;
    static double width = 1.0 / numRects;
    long start, end;
    private static final Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1);

    public Pi(long start, long end){
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end; 
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(long i = start; i < end; i++){
            try{
                s.acquire();
            }catch (InterruptedException IE){ 
                return;
            }
            pi += Math.sqrt(1.0 - Math.pow(width * i, 2)) * width;
            s.release();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[(int)(numRects / rectsPerThread)];
        double start = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i  = 0; i < threads.length; i++){
            threads[i] = new Thread(new Pi(i * rectsPerThread, i * rectsPerThread + rectsPerThread));
            threads[i].start();
        }

        for(Thread t : threads){
            try{
                t.join();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        pi *= 4;
        System.out.println(pi);
        System.out.printf("Ran in: %.4fms", (System.nanoTime() - start) / Math.pow(10, 6));
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I have updated my original question with additional code, using an external synchronized add method in order to make the adding thread safe. Why would using a semaphore work, while using a synchronized add method would not work?

Comment: Synchronised methods work in the same object; i.e. it guarantees mutual exclusion within the same instance of Pi. You are creating a new Pi each time.

Comment: I have made my Pi variable static. Unless my understanding of what a static variable is is highly off, that means that I have only one instance of pi.

Comment: You have one instance of pi variable, yes, but there are many instances of class Pi. Each synchronised "add" function guarantees that no two threads can execute the "add" function of the same Pi object at the same time. With the Pi object instances being separate, the threads happily performs conflicting updates on the pi static variable.

notice the uppercase "Pi" and lowercase "pi"

Comment: Thank you so much! My understanding of what it meant for a function to be synchronized was off, as I, for whatever reason, assumed that it would be synchronized across all instances of the class, not only the instance in which it was initially called. I changed my code so that instead of adding to a global pi variable as each part was calculated, it calculated all parts first, and then added all calculated parts. Thank you again :)

Comment: Might be faster to use a [`DoubleAdder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/DoubleAdder.html).